# How to override SecurityFilterChain in Spring Boot context?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-autoconfiguration

I am facing the issue which is not obvious to resolve just by reading the documentation. While migrating to Spring Boot v2.7.4 / Spring Security v5.7.3 I have refactored the configuration not to extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and to look like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
            csrf().disable().
            logout().disable().
            authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The above method is called, however has no effect as `SecurityFilterChain` instance created by [`OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/6e3a87d315ae92f630adc577a6678075f2f014a0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/servlet/OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.java#L158) is used instead (I see that from debug by inspecting the list of filter in the stack that has e.g. `LogoutFilter` which should be disabled by above configuration). Debug log:

```
2022-10-20 15:49:48.790 [main] o.s.b.a.s.DefaultWebSecurityCondition    : Condition DefaultWebSecurityCondition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration$OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration matched due to AllNestedConditions 2 matched 0 did not; NestedCondition on DefaultWebSecurityCondition.Beans @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter,org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans; NestedCondition on DefaultWebSecurityCondition.Classes @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain', 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity'
2022-10-20 15:49:48.791 [main] a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration$OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration'
2022-10-20 15:49:48.792 [main] o.s.b.a.condition.OnBeanCondition        : Condition OnBeanCondition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration$OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration#jwtSecurityFilterChain matched due to @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'jwtDecoderByJwkKeySetUri'
...
2022-10-20 15:49:49.082 [main] a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.mycompany.CustomSecurityConfig.filterChain()
...
2022-10-20 15:49:52.276 [main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for any request
2022-10-20 15:50:13.348 [main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@33502cfe, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@729d1428, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7d0312a, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6ca97ddf, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@38f569d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1104ad6a, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@74ab8610, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7833407, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@66acaa54, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@115924ba, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6a905513, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5749e633, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@49741e80]
...
2022-10-20 15:50:13.384 [main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for any request
2022-10-20 15:50:17.641 [main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@4a0f4282, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@19d3f4fb, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@99f75e4, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@118c1faa, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2b6ff016, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5aefdb9e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@43cf97a8, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@da5b46f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@11267e87, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@7827cdfc]
```

Is it expected that the bean `CustomSecurityConfig.filterChain` participates in `DefaultWebSecurityCondition` evaluation and `OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration.jwtSecurityFilterChain` is not created. Or the issue with [`DefaultWebSecurityCondition`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/6e3a87d315ae92f630adc577a6678075f2f014a0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/DefaultWebSecurityCondition.java#L43) is that the instance of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is not in the context anymore (as to [issue #10822](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822) it is deprecated)?

The [suggestion to add `@Order()` annotation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822#issuecomment-1035919673) didn't work:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { ...
```

as well as further attempts to exclude the autoconfiguration class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(excludeName = "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer { ...
```

failed probably due to [issue #5427](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5427) with the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
    - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.handleInvalidExcludes(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:222) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
```

This way also does not work:

```
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = ".*OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.*")})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer { ...
```

The documentation I read before posting:

- [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)
- [Spring Security: Upgrading the Deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter)
- [Spring Security - How to Fix WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Deprecated](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/fix-websecurityconfigureradapter-deprecated)

**Update**

I have created a [small Maven project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mg7up88d5m0eba/spring-test.7z?dl=1) that demonstrates the issue. After project is started, request the controller like this:

```
$ wget -nv -O - 'http://localhost:8080/spring/test'
Username/Password Authentication Failed.
```

As one can see, the custom configured `SecurityFilterChain` is not active because otherwise the access would be granted (as to `antMatchers( "/**/test").permitAll()`). `ContextRefreshedEvent` listener dumps two `SecurityFilterChain` instances (`jwtSecurityFilterChain` and `filterChain`), the priority of them is not possible to configure reliably.

Comment: I think your CustomSecurityConfig  should extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: I think you've missed the whole story: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is now marked as deprecated, take a look at documentation links from the post.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible sample?

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I have created a [small project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mg7up88d5m0eba/spring-test.7z?dl=1) that reproduces the issue. See updated post.

Comment: With that small project, I think you should open an issue in Spring Boot https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues

Comment: As follows from [issue #33103](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33103#issuecomment-1310815121), the beans imported from XML via `@ImportResource` do not participate in Spring Boot autoconfiguration, hence beans scanning should be performed using annotation i.e. `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "some.package")` – this basically solves the issue.